# Estimate on rate of growth of a power series

Tags: power-series

Given two sequences $(a_k),(b_k)$ with $a_k\geq0,b_k>0$ such that the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k b_kr^{k}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kr^k$ converge for each $r>0$. My question now is: Does there exist a constant $c$ (depending only on $(b_k))$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kb_kr^{k}\geq c\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kr^{k}
\end{align*}
for all large $r>0$? This is obvious for if $(b_k)$ is bounded away from zero, but what if $\liminf b_k=0?$
In my case, $b_k=1/k!$, and I have no idea how to approach this problem...
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the contrary.  Let $f(r) = \sum_{k} a_k b_k r^k$ and $g(r) = \sum_k a_k r^k$, and suppose all $a_k > 0$.
If $b_k \to 0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ take $N$ so that 
$b_k < \epsilon$ for $k \ge N$.  Now for $r$ sufficiently large (say $r > R$), 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_k b_k r^k < r^{N-1} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_k b_k < a_N b_N r^N < \sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k b_k r^k $$
Thus for $r > R$ we have
$$f(r)  < 2 \sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k b_k r^k < 2 \epsilon \sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k r^k < 2 \epsilon g(r)$$

Answer (score 1):

No, take $a_k = 1/k!,b_k=1/2^k.$ Then $\sum a_kr^k = e^r, \sum a_kb_kr^k = e^{r/2}.$